# Как определить входит ли символ в строку

Tags: jquery, строки, javascript

Собственно вопрос, ка определить есть ли в ссылке http:// получаю с помощью

$(this).attr("href");

Comment: Начать с [основ](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/foundation), изучить [базовые типы](http://javascript.ru/basic/types#string), работу со [строками](http://javascript.ru/String) и [regexp](http://javascript.ru/basic/regular-expression).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this).attr("href").indexOf("http://") + 1
```

Если возвращает положительное значение, значит есть. Если ноль - нету.